# Ajax/Jquery Redirect call does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So from my php, I am echoing {error:1}:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        register();
    });
});

function register(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"submit.php",
        async : false,
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg.error)==1){
                window.location="index.html";
            }
            else if(parseInt(msg.error)==0){  
                $('#error_out').html(msg.error);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it does not want to redirect. Instead it return "submit.php" with 1 echoed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't just have a return of 1, as that wouldn't be JSON.  If you're just returning '1' and doing a parseInt on it, set the dataType to 'html'.

---

If you want JSON, do this in your PHP:

```
$return = array('code'=>1);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Your 'success' function would look like this:

```
if(msg.code==1){
    window.location="index.html";
}
else if(msg.code==0)
{
    $('#error_out').html(msg.code);
    e.preventDefault();
}
else 
{ 
   // handle any other return value.
}
```

---

Ok, my fault for not reading the problem properly.  The problem is that you're submitting the form, and not cancelling it properly.  Do this in your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        register();
    });
});
```

You can remove the one in your failure case.  That one doesn't do anything, since the stack would have already cleared by the time the async function came back (if it did at all).

Comment: I know, i know, what i am returning is a json (in my code). Just wanted to make it simpler to read. The json part works, the error jquery displaying divs work, its just that it is not redirecting me. I am actually using in my code msg.txt which represents the url

Comment: Don't simplify a test case that much without testing that it, too is broken... build one that exhibits the same behavior.  : )

Any which way, perhaps my additional comments will help, otherwise we'll need to actually see more code.

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is the exact thing i have in my php code. It is my fault for writing 1 instead of the full json.

Comment: Should work in IE, given the code above.  Most likely candidate for something working everywhere but IE is an extra comma inside your $.ajax call (or something similar if you've got more code).

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent form from submiting itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        register();

        e.preventDefault(); // Or return false;
    });
});
```

Your form submits and ajax does not have chance to work its callbacks.

Comment: So when can i submit my form?

Comment: Do You need to submit Your form? From code samples I make impression that You are using form just as wrapper for Your ajax call.

Comment: If no errors occurs, i want to submit and redirect otherwise nothing except do the jquery stuff.

Comment: You've already submitted the form through AJAX.  You don't need to submit the data again.